# Can I use System.Timers as an alternative to Thread.Sleep() when testing with C# and Selenium in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to replace all (or at least most) the Thread.Sleep() in my tests and it seems System.Timers can do the work but I don't know how to implement it.

Or if you guys know another replacement please let me know.

I would really appreciate it if somebody helps me here.

Thank you.

Edit: Sorry, it's my first question here, I should have given an example:

```
public void AdditionalCardIssueNoBankBranchSelected()
    {
        
        additionalCardApplicationPage.ClearBankConsultantCodeField();
        additionalCardApplicationPage.TypeSalesOfficer();
        additionalCardApplicationPage.TypeEIKBankCustomerAndPressGetDataButton();
        additionalCardApplicationPage.ChooseMainCard();
        chooseMainCardPage.TypeCustomerEikAndPressSearchButton();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        bankCardSearchPage.SelectFirstValidBankCardOther();
        chooseMainCardPage.PressChooseMainCardButton();
        additionalCardApplicationPage.PressStartApplicationButton();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
        alert.Accept();
        Assert.IsTrue(additionalCardApplicationPage.BankBranchCodeAlert.Displayed);
    }
```

So pretty much everywhere I have `Thread.Sleep()` is because I am waiting for the page to load in full because if it doesn't next action will not happen as the element I want to interact with is not visible yet.
Sometimes bankCardSearchPage.SelectFirstValidBankCardOther() will not go thru because the table where the cards are is not visible yet.

I hope I explained it well. Thank you.

Comment: Can you at least give an example of code you want `Thread.Sleep()` replaced in?

Comment: so you basically want to roll your own `Thread.Sleep()`?

Comment: yes, basically I want to roll my own Thread.Sleep()

Comment: What is the motivation behind the desire to replace the `Thread.Sleep(1000);` with a timer? Do you want to prevent the current thread from being blocked, so that your application is more responsive?

Comment: Theodor Zoulias, it seems timer is not what I need here, but another kind of explicit wait like the one cruisepandey was kind enough to help me with. I just knew that Thread.Sleep is not good and should be replaced and was looking for solution online and thought timer will do the work but now I know. Thank you for trying to help anyway :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Thread.sleep()
```

is an explicit wait but worst of it's kind.

best one is below (Explicit wait):

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//span[text()='OK']/..")));
```

You can pretty much replace everything with the dynamic wait mentioned above.

What it would do is that to look for web element in DOM for every `500ms` `until 20 seconds` (as we `have defined 20 in the above object creation`), if found it would return the `web element`, if not a `Timeout exception will be raised.`

Comment: Thank you for the help! It seems to be working!

So what I did is add "var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));" as a first line in my test, but as I have many tests - where should I put it so it applies to all of them? I tried to put it in the TextFixture where I declare the pages I am using, but "var" is not good there - it should be declared in a different way? also "driver" - cannot reference the non - static field, method or property?

Comment: do you have TestBase class ? if yes create a global variable in TestBase and that should have visibility in all of your Test classes or utility classes. you can create object of `WebDriverWait` in TestBase constructor.